# como puedo mostrar cuantos sueldos hay mayores de 1000

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, bucles

Cordial saludos amigos tengo un trabajo que no he podido terminar, mi tarea es la siguiente:

> Pedir 10 sueldos. Mostrar su suma y cuantos hay mayores de $1000

Tengo como pedir e imprimir los 10 sueldos y mostrar la suma total de ellos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner h = new Scanner(System.in);
    /*creo mi vector para almacenar 10 sueldos*/
    int[] vector = new int[10];
    /*variable para sumar los sueldos*/
    int sumadsueldos=0;
    String texto;
    /*utilizo el ciclo for para llenar mi vector*/
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println("introduse los sueldos");
        vector[i]=h.nextInt();
        if(vector[i]>=0){
            /*suma interactiva del vector*/
            sumadsueldos+=vector[i];
            texto="total de sueldo sumados:";
            System.out.println(texto+sumadsueldos);
        }
    }
    /*para mostrar los 10 sueldos*/
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.print(vector[i]+",");
    }
}
```

}

Para mostrar cuantos sueldos hay mayores de 1000 intente colocar un segundo condicional asi:

```
if(int i>1000){ System.out.println(i); }
```

Pero no me resulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entendí bien la pregunta requieres sumar los sueldos mayores a 1,000.

De ser así, pudieras hacer esto:

```
/*para mostrar los 10 sueldos*/
int sueldosMayoresAMil = 0;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    System.out.print(vector[i]+",");
    if (vector[i] > 1000) {
       sueldosMayoresAMil++;
    }
}
System.out.println(" mayores a mil="+sueldosMayoresAMil);
```

Comment: Excelente. Me sirvió mucho. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí un ejemplo para imprimir los sueldos mayores a 1000:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner h = new Scanner(System.in);
        /* creo mi vector para almacenar 10 sueldos */
        int[] vector = new int[10];
        /* variable para sumar los sueldos */
        int sumadsueldos = 0;
        String texto;
        /* utilizo el ciclo for para llenar mi vector */
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("introduse los sueldos");
            vector[i] = h.nextInt();
            if (vector[i] >= 0) {
                /* suma interactiva del vector */
                sumadsueldos += vector[i];
                texto = "total de sueldo sumados:";
                System.out.println(texto + sumadsueldos);
            }
        }
        /* para mostrar los 10 sueldos */
        List<Integer> listaSueldosMayores = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // LISTA QUE GUARDA LOS SUELDOS MAYORES A MIL
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(vector[i] + ",");
            if (vector[i] > 1000) { // CONDICION SUELDOS MAYORES A 1000
                listaSueldosMayores.add((Integer) vector[i]); //AGREGA A LA LISTA LOS SUELDOS MAYORES A MIL
            }
        }

        //IMPRIME LOS SUELDOS MAYORES A MIL
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("SUELDOS MAYORES A 1000 ");
        for (Integer num : listaSueldosMayores) {
            System.out.print(num + ", ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: La primera explicación es más sencilla y más fácil de ejecutar para mi como principiante. Muchas gracias por ayudarme a resolver mis dudas.